# Visual Studio Crashes trying to create Event Handler

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Visual Studio 2010
Designing a webpage. Have been doing this for awhile, never had this problem.  i reinstalled, i reset the settings, both are what my google searches told me to do.  this has not fixed the problem.

when i double click a control to create the handler and go to the code page, it crashes. 
when i go to the properties and try to set an event handler, it crashes.

this just all of a sudden started happening.  any ideas?

Comment: Please provide more detail. Does it happen with a new project, just adding a button and a click event?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Try this. Close the vs, and go to the project directory, and delete (first backup it) the xxxxx.suo file of the project. This file is hidden.

Comment: @Aristos: What? why would I do that?

Comment: @JohnSaunders Oh, a big apology, I send wrong message, I type Jo, and give me first your name and not the one that make the question. this is for the one that make this question.